# preg replace wiki tag

Tags: regex, preg-replace

I am trying to replace string:

```
[[Rock music|rock]], [[blues]], [[soul music|soul]], [[pop music|pop]],[[Have a Little Faith (Joe Cocker album)|Have a Little Faith]]
```

to:

```
rock, blues, soul, pop, Have a Little Faith
```

what is proper regex?

I tested this pattern `/\[[[\w\s]+\W(.*)\]],/` but not worked.

Comment: What did you use as the replacement?

Comment: @Barmar $1 but the result was unusable string.

Comment: You need to use a non-greedy `.*?`. `.*` is greedy, so it will match everything to the last `]]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
'~\[\[(?:[^][|]+\|)?([^][|]+)]]~'
```

And replace with `$1`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jL1tM2/2)

*Explanation*:

- `\[\[` - literal `[[`
- `(?:[^][|]+\|)?` - optional (1 or 0) 1+ characters other than `[`, `]`, and `|` up to the literal `|`
- `[^][|]+` - Group 1: 1+ characters other than `[`, `]`, and `|`
- `]]` - literal `]]`

[PHP demo:](http://ideone.com/tPSrE8)

```
$str = "[[Rock music|rock]], [[blues]], [[soul music|soul]], [[pop music|pop]], [[Have a Little Faith (Joe Cocker album)|Have a Little Faith]] "; 
$result = preg_replace('~\[\[(?:[^][|]+\|)?([^][|]+)]]~', "$1", $str);
echo $result;
```

Comment: thanks and if string contain () like: [[Have a Little Faith (Joe Cocker album)|Have a Little Faith]]

Comment: As I noted, then use `\[\[(?:[^][|]+\|)?([^][|]+)]]`. See the updated answer.

Comment: Why did you use `~` delimiter instead of `/` ?

Comment: thank you wiktor its worked very well. i edited question to match last edit.